# App stop working when Google Drive File Picker intent launched

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to implement posibility to export and import (to and from Google Drive respectively) to my app, in the same Activity.

The export function works perfectly. For the import function, I have thought to use the Google Drive File Picker from play services in order to get the id of the txt file to import, and after that, read the file and import it to my database.

Well, first of all I connect to Google Api Client, that it's ok cause it works for export. 
At the onConnected method I use a switch for distingue between import or export:

```
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    switch(driveCase){
        case 0:
            Log.i(TAG, "API client connected for export.");
            saveFileToDrive();
            break;
        case 1:
            Log.i(TAG, "API client connected for import.");
            pickFileFromDrive();
            readFileFromDrive();
            break;
    }
}
```

First I want to show the GDrive file picker, so:

```
private void pickFileFromDrive(){
    Log.i(TAG, "Open FilePicker Activity.");
    IntentSender intentPicker = Drive.DriveApi
            .newOpenFileActivityBuilder()
            .setMimeType(new String[] { "text/plain" })
            .build(mGoogleApiClient);



    try {
        startIntentSenderForResult(
                intentPicker, REQUEST_CODE_OPENER, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
      Log.w(TAG, "Unable to send intent", e);
    }


}
```

And this is the point where app crashes, the file picker is shown but my app stops working...

Here is the onActivityResult:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Taking result...");

            DriveId driveId = (DriveId) data.getParcelableExtra(
                    OpenFileActivityBuilder.EXTRA_RESPONSE_DRIVE_ID);
            pickedDriveId = driveId;

            Log.i(TAG, "Result Toke.");
        finish();

    }
```

Any idea about what could be the reason?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
This is the logcat trace

```
    08-30 22:25:33.110: E/SyncSchedulerImpl(25559): Ignoring sync request:  rate limited (on connection limit)
08-30 22:25:33.180: I/android-drive-quickstart(26434): API client connected for import.
08-30 22:25:33.180: I/android-drive-quickstart(26434): Open FilePicker Activity.
08-30 22:25:33.188: I/ActivityManager(401): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.PICK cmp=com.google.android.gms/.drive.data.ui.open.OpenFileActivityDelegate (has extras)} from pid -1
08-30 22:25:33.727: W/ActivityManager(401): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41e01cc8 u0 com.example.estudiame/.MyTestsActivity}
08-30 22:25:34.008: D/dalvikvm(401): GC_EXPLICIT freed 5376K, 38% free 32505K/52376K, paused 4ms+22ms, total 193ms
08-30 22:25:34.133: I/ActivityManager(401): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.drive.data.ui.open.OpenFileActivityDelegate: +400ms
08-30 22:25:34.157: E/SyncSchedulerImpl(25559): Ignoring sync request:  rate limited (on connection limit)
08-30 22:25:34.196: I/BaseActivity(25559): GoogleApiClient connected
08-30 22:25:34.212: D/dalvikvm(25559): GC_CONCURRENT freed 361K, 4% free 11087K/11480K, paused 3ms+8ms, total 57ms
08-30 22:25:44.462: W/ActivityManager(401): Activity stop timeout for ActivityRecord{41e01cc8 u0 com.example.estudiame/.MyTestsActivity}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Please publish your logcat trace.

Comment: No one knows how to fix it? I have try, but without success.